# swagger.json is not generated in Jersey + Spring + Tomcat environment

Tags: java, api, tomcat, jersey, swagger

I've gone through Swagger documentation and configured it according to the documentation.

When I request http://localhost:8080/rest/api-docs page, Swagger shows all information correctly, but it don't generate swagger.json, so http://localhost:8080/rest/swagger.json returns 404.

My endpoint http://localhost:8080/rest/test also works fine.

Here is my `web.xml`:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.JerseyConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Swagger Config -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>api.version</param-name>
        <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080/rest/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

`JerseyConfig` class:

```
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(Test.class);
        //....
        // Swagger
        register(com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
        register(com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing.ApiListingResourceJSON.class);
        register(com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing.JerseyApiDeclarationProvider.class);
        register(com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing.JerseyResourceListingProvider.class);
    }
}
```

`Test.class` is a simple endpoint, annotated with Swagger @Api.

```
@Path("/test")
@Api(value = "/test", description = "tttttt")
public class TestResource {

   @GET
   @ApiOperation(value = "Checks server")
   @ApiResponses(@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Server is available"))
   public Response check() {
       return Response.ok().build();
   }
}
```

App is deployed in Tomcat.

---

According to Jersey ResourceModel, the only endpoints created by Swagger are:

```
   GET     /api-docs
   GET     /api-docs/{route: .+}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `swagger.json` location is the recommended location for the swagger definition, however it's not the *only* place it can be generated.  Please try putting the `api-docs` location in your swagger-ui and it should work fine.